# Pass pointer of struct with recursive function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary-tree

I'm just trying to pass my struct in recursive function, but in the function when I will pass it again it will be the argument of my struct.
I could get the right value but I get the error "passing argument 1 of 'search' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]gcc
"

```
typedef struct node_t
{
int keyVal;
struct node_t *leftNode;
struct node_t *rightNode;
struct node_t *parent;
}Node;

typedef struct tree_t
{
 struct node_t *root;
}List;



Node *search( List *temp, int value)
    {  
        Node *curr=temp->root;
       if (curr == NULL || curr->keyVal == value)
           return curr;
        if (curr->keyVal < value)


      return search(&(curr->leftNode), value); //here I'm getting a warning
                     ^^^ 
    return search(&(curr->leftNode), value); //the same here 
}                ^^^
```

Comment: BTW this warning should always be considered as an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node *search( List *temp, int value)` This takes a `List` aka `tree_t` as the first argument.

In `return search(&(curr->leftNode), value);` the `curr->leftNode` is a `Node` aka `node_t`. This is different type and the compiler is correct to complain about incompatible pointer type.

A possible fix would be to change the function signature to `Node * search( Node * curr, int value)` and remove `Node *curr=temp->root;`. Do the first call initiating the search as `search(x->root, xxx);` with your `List`. The recursive calls would then be correct.

Comment: so we can't fix this warning? or can't we make them as the same type? and thanks for ur answer

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The code as it appears in your question is insufficient to determine your intent.

Comment: I'm only trying to delete this warning(passing argument 1 of 'search' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]gcc) the code is working for me but my doctor said that I could fix delete this warning somehow.

Comment: It is only working because of unintended consequences.

Comment: I was asking about the intent of the code not if you intend to get rid of the warning.

Comment: it's a binary tree and I have to make about 7 function, the search function would help me to get the max, min, successor and the predecessor.

Comment: Would the suggested fix in my answer be sufficient?